# Low stereo volume from pc sound

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, stereo

Not sure where to put this but I'm having an issue with the sound from my stereo. I have a standard set of 2.1 pc speakers hooked to the pc and an rca plug ran to my stereo. Sound from 2.1 is perfect but the sound from the stereo is very low as in I have to turn the stereo up full blast to hear it. double checked all connections and wires. everything is in good condition, just can't get decent sound from the stereo. Anyone run into this issue before and if so is there a cure?

Comment: RCA plug from where, precisely?

Comment: From onboard sound output.

Comment: Could you maybe take a picture? Computers don't usually have RCA outputs, hence my question.

Comment: My apologies for not clarifying that the cable I use is a Aux to rca cable.

Comment: That really doesn't tell me anything more. That's why I asked for a picture, as words weren't working. We need to know precisely what output, what input, what cable. 'aux' is really not an adequate description.